# vim-latex installation

Tags: vim, vim-latex

I have attempted to install vim-latex (Latex-suite) with Pathogen, though I seem to have (at least partially failed). I followed the instructions given in the answer [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/13744/how-to-install-vim-latex-plugin), though upon following them, `help: latex-suite.txt` yields the message `E149: Sorry, no help for latex-suite.txt`, which seems to indicate that latex-suite has not been installed properly. If I use `:scriptnames`, I get (among other things) the following lines:

```
 13: ~/.vim/bundle/vim-latex/plugin/SyntaxFolds.vim
 14: ~/.vim/bundle/vim-latex/plugin/filebrowser.vim
 15: ~/.vim/bundle/vim-latex/plugin/imaps.vim
 16: ~/.vim/bundle/vim-latex/plugin/remoteOpen.vim
```

which seems to contradict this, though the plugin itself does not seem to work. How should I go about fixing this. I am using vim on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: The same issue happens with `:help latex-suite` as well.

Comment: Installing **any** plugin via Pathogen does not automatically generate/configure help for that plugin in vim.  See https://stackoverflow.com/q/6970334 and https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen#runtime-path-manipulation which discusses `:helptags` and `:Helptags`.

Answer (score 1):

I've put together a bunch of resources for writing LaTeX and Markdown in NeoVim on my YouTube [channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCOi2wszcfvs0j9Pcom3z9VA) and GitHub [repo](https://github.com/benbrastmckie/.config). These include a video series which demonstrate the [resulting functionality](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLBYZ1xfnKeDToZ2XXbUGSC7BkorWdyNh3) of the configuration, as well as providing an [installation guide](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLBYZ1xfnKeDRbxgKSDZ-41U3DF9foKC1J), a [configuration guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oyEPY6xFhs0&list=PLBYZ1xfnKeDT0LWxQQma8Yh-IfpmQ7UHr) for adapting my configuration to your needs, and [instructions for using Git to collaborate with others](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GIJG4QtZBYI&list=PLBYZ1xfnKeDQYYXIhKKrXhWOaSphnn9ZL). I have also provided a [Cheat Sheet](https://github.com/benbrastmckie/.config/blob/master/CheatSheet.md) with all of the key-bindings that I have included for writing LaTeX documents with NeoVim. I hope that this is of some use to you! Feel free to spread the word to others looking for contemporary tools for academic writing!